# How to enable/disable listview subitem editing

Tags: c#, listview, edit, subitem

I've created a checked listview programmatically, with one of the columns being an editable textbox. I want to enable or disable the subitem on each row according to the state of the checkbox, but can't find a property or a way to access the subitem's edit state. I've tried to cast the subitem back to a control, but that didn't work as well.

Comment: You will have to overlay a Textobox to achieve that. Except if you want only one coulmn to be editable: Then you can simply change the order of the columns and display Item (ie SubItems[0]) further to the right.. - If you are already doing that use LabelEdit to allow/disallow editing; or post the code you have. If you want to change the edit state for individual rows you can try to change it in the selectionchanged event.. Or consider switching to a DataGridView

Comment: What do you mean by "overlaying a TextBox"?
In my case only one column is actually editable, but the SubItem[X] doesn't have an enabled property. Furthermore, I tried to create a list of TextBoxes, that holds reference to the same controls in the ListView, to try and influence it that way, but in order to manage that I need the control's name, which I can't get as well.

Comment: Well if you only need to edit one subitem you don't need textboxes. you can try to use the `ItemCheck` event: `yourLV.LabelEdit = !e.CurrentValue.HasFlag(CheckState.Checked);` - Note that afaik the checkboxes will always sit in the item1.

Comment: Contrary to the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) the currentstate is the one before the change, hence the `!` (or go for `ItemChecked` event!) - You still need to code the Selectionindexchanges: `            if (listView2.SelectedIndices.Count <= 0) return;
            int i = listView2.SelectedIndices[0];
            listView2.LabelEdit = listView2.Items[0].Checked;`

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but The LabelEdit didn't give me any results. 
I did manage to find a somewhat ugly solution. 
I created a list of those same textboxes and as I added a textbox to a listviewitem, I added a tag to the subitem with the textbox's name. Now all I have to do is get that name, locate it in the list and enable/disable it from there.

Comment: I can't post any script in here, cause my workplace environment doesn't enable copy-paste to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used. I hope there's a more elegant one:
I created a List of TextBoxes and as I added a textbox to a ListViewItem I also added it to the list. In addition, I added a Tag to each ListViewItem with the TextBox's name. Now, when I check or uncheck a certain row I get the name of the control from the tag via lstItemList.Items[e.Index].SubItems[3].Tag.ToString() and search for it in the list. I change the Enabled property of the located TextBox.